# Unable to set MaxFormContentSize in jetty embedded server

Tags: jetty, embedded-jetty

I've looked at all the suggestions and I am trying to set the max content size value to a small (700) just to prove I can change it. Jetty 9.4.41.

When I send a POST like:

```
0000:   POST /data1/MaxRequestSize/MyTryURL01 HTTP/1.1\r\n
0030:   Accept: application/xml,application/atom+xml\r\n
005E:   User-Agent: xxxxxxxxxxx\r\n
0077:   Content-Type: application/atom+xml; charset=utf-8\r\n
00AA:   Host: localhost:9090\r\n
00C0:   Connection: keep-alive\r\n
00D8:   Content-Length: 808\r\n
00ED:   \r\n
...
```

I get no error (i.e 808 > 700).

Extracting my server startup code:

```
HandlerCollection       handlers        = new HandlerCollection();
System.setProperty( "org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.maxFormContentSize", "700" ); /**1**/
server = new Server();
server.setHandler( handlers );
server.setAttribute( "org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.maxFormContentSize", 700 ); /**2**/

// Setting up connection
ServerConnector serverConn      = null;
HttpConfiguration httpConfig    = new HttpConfiguration();
httpConfig.setSendServerVersion( false );
httpConfig.setSendXPoweredBy( false );
HttpConnectionFactory hcf = new HttpConnectionFactory( httpConfig );
serverConn = new ServerConnector( server, hcf );
server.addConnector( serverConn );
serverConn.setPort( httpPort );
serverConn.setName( Constants.CONF_HTTP_CONNECTOR );
serverConn.setReuseAddress( true );

// Initializing servlets
contextHandlers = new ContextHandlerCollection();
ServletHolder[] holders = new ServletHolder[ 1 ];
ServletHolder holder = new ServletHolder( myServlet );
holder.setInitParameter( ... );
ServletContextHandler handler = new ServletContextHandler();
handler.setMaxFormContentSize( 700 );                         /**3**/
handler.setContextPath( servicePath );
handler.setAllowNullPathInfo( true );
connectors = new String[ 2 ];
connectors[0] = "@" + Constants.CONF_HTTP_CONNECTOR;
connectors[1] = "@" + Constants.CONF_ADMIN_CONNECTOR;
handler.setVirtualHosts( connectors );
handler.setDisplayName( "foo" );
handler.addServlet( holder, "/*" );
contextHandlers.addHandler( handler );

// Launching
handlers.addHandler( contextHandlers );
server.start();
```

Any suggestion appreciated.

Comment: I looked at the Jetty code, ContextHandler does in fact pull _maxFormContentSize from the environment with Integer.getInteger(MAX_FORM_CONTENT_SIZE_KEY, DEFAULT_MAX_FORM_CONTENT_SIZE); during instance initialization. Therefore /**1**/ should have worked.

Comment: If you have a `multipart/form-data` content, then the servlet spec `MultipartConfigElement` is used to configure the max sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Jetty only enforces a max limit for application/x-www-form-urlencoded. My tests did not use that particular encoding.

Comment: Tip: don't use the properties, use `ServletContextHandler.setMaxFormContentSize(int)` and `ServletContextHandler.setMaxFormKeys(int)` instead.